# Disable dark mode on widget?

Tags: swift, widget, ios13, today-extension, ios-darkmode

I disabled the dark mode on the whole app through the info.plist but I'm not able to disable it on the Widget target

Do you know any solution?
Thank you

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I was not able to disable the dark mode on today extension in any way